# how to add a unique ID into a class with javascript/jquery

Tags: jquery, uniqueidentifier

in a javascript I have this case:

```
 case 'code':
                    var multiline = $(TextArea).hasSelection().indexOf('\n') >= 0;
                    if (multiline) {
                        var thisOpts = $.extend(htmlOpts, {
                            opentag: '<pre class="CodeBlock"><code>',
                            closetag: '</code></pre>',
                            opener: '',
                            closer: '',
                            closeslice: ''
                        });
                        $(TextArea).insertRoundTag('', thisOpts);
                    } else {
                        $(TextArea).insertRoundTag('code', htmlOpts, {'class': 'CodeInline'});
                    }
                    break;
```

How can I add a unique id to the class **CodeBlock** 
So the output should be something like:

```
<pre class="CodeBlock385619563354"><code>
```

Comment: What's the purpose of a unique class? O.o

Comment: What I am trying to achieve is to catch all the code with a anchor and rel attribute with the same uniqueID

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You could use Date object to create unique id.

```
var uniqueId = (new Date).getTime();
```

and then add it to your class:

```
opentag: '<pre class="codeBlock' + uniqueId + '"><code>'
```